# How to check linear independence of categorical features with a numerical target?

Tags: correlation, python, categorical-data, pearson-r, spearman-rho

Suppose I am doing linear regression on a dataset. My dataset contains columns ***f1, f2 ,f3 ,f4 , f5 , target***
. Features (independent variables) are the column names starting with "***f***" and my target variable (dependent variable) is "***target***". The columns **f1, f2, f3** are numerical columns (like values of temperature, humidity etc), whereas ***f4***, and ***f5*** are somewhat categorical ones (month, holiday, etc)

I am trying to check how strongly bonded are these variables to each other as well as the target variable. With Python, usually people run `sns.heatmap(data.corr())`, which returns Pearson correlations of the columns in a nice heatmap. I have read that this may not be the correct approach for everything. Its okay for numerical variables. Is it correct?

If it is, then what should be the approach with categorical columns? (ordinal as well as nominal)? Specially in a setting where I am trying to check all my categorical columns to the ***target*** (which is a numeric variable). I read about using Spearman's correlation. But I am not sure.

I would also appreciate if you could tell me an approach that can be used in the same heatmap.

Comment: I deleted my answer because there are some components of time-series analysis that I am less educated on (which in the case of your month variable may qualify), so I would rather let other more qualified people provide an answer on that question.  An example of how complicated correlations can get with time series data can be found [here](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/%7Edstephens/OldCourses/204-2007/Handouts/Yule1926.pdf)